# Unmarshalling, manipulating and then marshalling CVS data in Camel using Spring DSL

Tags: spring, csv, apache-camel, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm new to Camel / Spring DSL. I'm trying to use Camel 2.14.1 to unmarshal CSV data files, manipulate the columns of data (shift columns and apply arithmetic operations to values in those columns) and then marshal the data back into new CSV data files.

My log messages indicate that I can unmarshal my CSV data into a Java `List<Map<String,Object>>` collection and then marshal that collection back into CSV data (but unchanged, except that the column headings in the input CSV data are lost).

1. How to I get access the unmarshalled Java collection in Spring DSL ?
2. Can I implement all of the manipulation in Spring DSL only ? Or must I implement and use a Java Bean ?
3. Why do I lose the column headings in my CSV data during my unmarshal/marshal process ?
4. I've found some posting that suggest using `CSVStrategy` and `CSVConfig` from Apache Commons CSV but have not been particularly clear how. Is this the correct direction ?

I should add that I have implemented the same exercise using Java DSL with a Camel Processor that works on the Camel Exchange object.

My input CSV test data looks like this:

```
ColumnA,ColumnB
10,11
20,22
30,33
```

My output CSV test data looks like this:

```
10,11
20,22
30,33
```

My Spring DSL files is below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- requires camel-spring.jar -->
    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="CsvFileToQueueRoute">
            <!-- it seems that CSV files need column headings in first line -->
            <from uri="file:data/input?include=.*.csv&amp;noop=true" />
            <log
                message="Reading file from data/input : ${header.CamelFileAbsolutePath}" />
            <!-- convert CSV data into Java List-Map data (see useMaps=true) -->
            <unmarshal>
                <csv delimiter="," useMaps="true" />
            </unmarshal>
            <log message="Reading file from data/input : ${body}" />
            <to uri="activemq:csv.data" />
        </route>
        <route id="QueueToFileRoute">
            <from uri="activemq:csv.data" />
            <marshal>
                <csv autogenColumns="true" delimiter="," useMaps="true" />
            </marshal>
            <log message="Writing message from activemq:csv.data : ${headers}" />
            <to
                uri="file:data/output/csv.data?fileName=${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.SSS}.csv" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

My short Java program which uses my Spring DSL file is below.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CsvUnmarshalSpringDsl
{
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvUnmarshalSpringDsl.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        LOGGER.info("CsvUnmarshalSpringDsl");

        ApplicationContext myAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "file:src/main/resources/CsvUnmarshalSpringDsl.xml");

        CamelContext myCamelContext = (CamelContext) myAppContext.getBean("camelContext");

        myCamelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        myCamelContext.stop();
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) myAppContext).close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar question, just purified to immediate marshalling after unmarshal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800601/convert-csv-file-to-json-file-with-apache-camel-via-list-of-maps. Have you managed to achieve your goal - manipulate list of maps after unmarshal? Can you provide an answer to your own question?